# making sure google maps location opens in aus

Tags: google-maps

I am passing to google maps as part of an app I have built

I pass to google using the following url

https://maps.google.com/maps?z=17&q=93+Sheridan+Street%40-16.9212687,145.7713489

the problem is that the maps part loads up the correct part but the directions on the left hand side are for america! - not really what i am looking for.

is there anyway in url to force the address to just show AUS so the directions and map show AUS and not USA.

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the Australian top level domain:

https://maps.google.com.au/maps?z=17&q=93+Sheridan+Street%40-16.9212687,145.7713489